# Alguma forma de pegar o preço do dolar

Tags: php, api

Vocês sabem da existência de alguma api ou outra maneira em php de pegar o preço do dolar? Eu só preciso do preço do dolar para o real. Eu já tentei essas duas api's, mas as duas estão fora do ar.
http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/valores?moedas=USD&alt=json
http://developers.agenciaideias.com.br/cotacoes/json

Obrigado!

Comment: Apenas atualizando, API facinha: https://docs.awesomeapi.com.br/api-de-moedas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o *Yahoo YQL*, através da Query: [`select Rate from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDBRL")`](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20Rate%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDBRL%22)), por exemplo, o `USDBRL` deve ser definido pelo que deseja, deste caso será retornado `3.1141`, ele parece ser atualizado em tempo real.

---

Você precisa precisa obter a resposta da seguinte maneira:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?
q=select%20Rate%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDBRL%22)
&format=json
&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
```

---

Basicamente utilize:

```
function converterMoeda(string $de, string $para){

    $parametros = [
        'q' => 'select Rate from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair = "'.$de.$para.'"',
        'env' => 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys',
        'format' => 'json'
    ];

    $parametros = http_build_query($parametros, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

    $ch = curl_init('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?'.$parametros);

    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1
    ]);

    if($resultado = curl_exec($ch)){

        $resultado = json_decode($resultado, true);

        return $resultado['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];

    }

    return false;

}
```

```
if($resultado = converterMoeda('USD', 'BRL')){
   echo $resultado;
}
```

Neste momento o resultado é 3.1141, mas logicamente irá mudar. Ele suporta várias moedas, inclusive Bitcoin, pode utilizar `BTCBRL` e retornará, agora, `3982.2249`.

Answer (score 5):

## Fixer.io

A [Fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) que é uma API gratuita e de simples uso.

Dando um GET no endereço http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=BRL você tem um JSON como resultado:

```
{"base":"USD","date":"2017-03-03","rates":{"BRL":3.1311}}
```

O banco de dados é da [European Central Bank](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html) e é atualizado uma vez por dia.

## currencylayer

Outra opção é o [Currency Layer](https://currencylayer.com/). Tem planos pagos e gratuitos, independente de qual for necessita de registro para usar. O gratuito é limitado a 1000 acessos por mês e os valores são atualizados a cada hora.

Outros planos aqui: https://currencylayer.com/product

Comment: Essa seria ótima se não fosse atualizada apenas uma vez por dia. Você conhece outras de graça? Alguma paga não seria inviável dependendo do cobrado, conhece também?

Comment: atualizei a resposta

Comment: O [Fixer.io](https://fixer.io/) não permite mais a consulta pela moeda base USD, a versão gratuita  agora é somente com a moeda base EUR.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o webservice do Banco Central:

http://blog.tiagocrizanto.com/configuracoes-do-webservice-do-banco-central-cotacoes-diversas/

Creio ser mais confiável e por ser um serviço estatal, não terá o risco de um desenvolvedor retirá-lo do ar quando quiser.

Segue um exemplo de como implementar:

```
<?php

// Mostra erros
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);

$debug = true;
$result = null;
$error = null;
$exception = null;
$xml = null;


// Definição da localização do arquivo WSDL
$wsdl = 'https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl';

// Soapclient PHP 5.0 ou Superior ( SOAP 1.1 e SOAP 1.2 )
$client = new Soapclient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => true));



$xml =' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://publico.ws.casosdeuso.sgs.pec.bcb.gov.br" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:getUltimoValorVO>
<in xsi:type="xsd:long">'. '206'.'</in>
</ns1:getUltimoValorVO>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
// Chamada do método SOAP
try {
    //$serie = 206;
    $result = $client->getUltimoValorVO($xml, $serie);

    if (is_object($result)) {
        if (!$result->getUltimoValorVOResult) {
            $error = $result->getUltimoValorVOError;
        }
    }

    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
        trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$result->faultcode}, faultstring: {$result->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $exception = $e->getMessage();
}

if ($debug) {
    echo '<h2>Request Headers</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequestHeaders()) . '</pre>';

    echo '<h2>Response Headers</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponseHeaders()) . '</pre>';

    echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . '</pre>';

    echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse()) . '</pre>';

    echo '<h2>Debug</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . var_dump($result) . '</pre>';

    echo '<h2>Exception</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . var_dump($exception) . '</pre>';

    echo '<h2>Error</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . $error . '</pre>';
}

?>
```

Comment: também recomendo pegar direto do banco central

Answer (score 2):

Segue mais um exemplo para utilização do webservice do BACEN.

Basta instanciar a classe BACEN e utilizar a função getUltimoValorXML para a ultima cotação ou getValor para cotação em uma data especifica.

Lembrando que o código para o dólar é 1.

```
class SOAP extends SOAPClient {

    private static $bacen_instance;

    private function SOAP($bacen_url) {
        return parent::__construct($bacen_url, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));
    }

    public static function getInstance($bacen_dados) {
        if (empty(self::$bacen_instance))
            self::$bacen_instance = new SOAP($bacen_dados);

        return self::$bacen_instance;
    }

    public function call($teste, $bacen_configuracoes) {
        return parent::__soapCall($teste, $bacen_configuracoes);
    }

}


class BACEN {
    private $bacen_url = "https://www3.bcb.gov.br/sgspub/JSP/sgsgeral/FachadaWSSGS.wsdl";

    /**
     *Função para acessar soap
     * @access public
     * @param array contendo os itens necessários para o retorno do webservice
     * @return objeto XML 
     */
    public function soap($teste, $bacen_conf){
        $bacen_cliente = SOAP::getInstance($this->bacen_url);

        $bacen_resultado = $bacen_cliente->call($teste, $bacen_conf);
        return ($bacen_resultado);        
    }   

    /**
     *

     */
    public function getUltimoValorXML($bacen_cod_moeda) {
        $bacen_conf[0] = 'getUltimoValorXML';
        $bacen_conf[1] = array('in0' => $bacen_cod_moeda);
        return $this->soap($bacen_conf);
    }

       /**
     *

     */
    public function getValor($bacen_cod_moeda, $databr) {
        $bacen_conf['in0'] = $bacen_cod_moeda;
        $bacen_conf['in1'] = $databr;
        $retorno = $this->soap('getValor', $bacen_conf);
        return $retorno;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando a API do Bacen:

```
$hoje = (new DateTime())->format('m-d-Y');
$uri = 'https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata/CotacaoDolarDia(dataCotacao=@dataCotacao)?@dataCotacao=\''.$hoje.'\'&$top=100&$format=json&$select=cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao';
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($uri));
var_dump($jsonData);
```